# Onclick buttons to move an element to different positions

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to move an element (eg. an image) to three different positions, when different divs are clicked.

eg. if *Button 01* is clicked, `padding-left=0px` is added to the image.

eg. if *Button 02* is clicked, `padding-left=30px` is added to the image.

eg. if *Button 03* is clicked, `padding-left=60px` is added to the image.

State 01

[image]

State 02

[image]

State 03

[image]

This is my first attempt, but is not moving the image.

```js
$('#cardEN').on('click', function() {
  $('.logo').removeClass('en');
  $(this).addClass('en');
});

$('#cardCN').on('click', function() {
  $('.logo').removeClass('cn');
  $(this).addClass('cn');
});

$('#cardAR').on('click', function() {
  $('.logo').removeClass('ar');
  $(this).addClass('ar');
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
}

.logo {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.en {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.cn {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.ar {
  padding-left: 60px;
}

.nav {
  padding-top: 100px
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logo"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1114318/pexels-photo-1114318.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" /></div>


<div class="nav">
  <div class="button" id="cardEN">Button 01</div>
  <div class="button" id="cardCN">Button 02</div>
  <div class="button" id="cardAR">Button 03</div>
</div>
```

Comment: my question is: why do you remove a class from `$(.logo)` but add a class to `$(this)`? `this` will refer to the element triggering the click event (the button) and that's why what is changing is the appearence of the button and not the element. You said that nothing happens but something happens instead

Comment: instead it's more better to use flex and change items to center or end or start on clicking button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add (and remove) classes to `.logo`. `$(this)` is refering to the clicked button not the `.logo` element, see below:

```js
$('#cardEN').on('click', function() {
  $('.logo').addClass('en').removeClass('cn ar');
});

$('#cardCN').on('click', function() {
  $('.logo').addClass('cn').removeClass('en ar');
});

$('#cardAR').on('click', function() {
  $('.logo').addClass('ar').removeClass('cn en');
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
}

.logo {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.en {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.cn {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.ar {
  padding-left: 60px;
}

.nav {
  padding-top: 100px
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logo"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1114318/pexels-photo-1114318.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" /></div>


<div class="nav">
  <div class="button" id="cardEN">Button 01</div>
  <div class="button" id="cardCN">Button 02</div>
  <div class="button" id="cardAR">Button 03</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost!. When clicking Button 01, it doesn't return to the beginning state.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I fixed it